# How to save programmatically as DXF?

Tags: inkscape, autocad

I need to save an Inkscape file as DXF for a laser cutter and a CNC router. The [Inkscape manual](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html) mentions I can save a file as DXF, which I do through the GUI and it works: `File` > `Save As` > `Desktop Plotting Cutter (AutoCAD DXF R14) (*.dxf)`. The manual also gives the example of manipulating and saving an SVG file through the command-line:

```
inkscape filename.svg --select=path1555 --verb=EditDuplicate --verb=ObjectRotate90 --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose
```

The list of verbs in the Inkscape command-line tools has only two references to DXF inside gcode options, and none to DXF:

```
> inkscape --verb-list | grep -i "dxf\|autocad"
ru.cnc-club.filter.gcodetools_dxfpoints_no_options: DXF Points...
ru.cnc-club.filter.gcodetools_dxfpoints_no_options.noprefs: DXF Points (No preferences)
```

How can I save a file as DXF programmatically?

Comment: Really unclear how this is a "graphic design" question.

Comment: @Scott I use Inkscape for graphic design and the CNC router for manufacturing. Shall I move the question to another forum, maybe engineering?

Comment: I think it's far more an engineering question than a design question. Graphic designers *rarely* use DXF format and I've yet to hear of one using CNC machines. But that's all merely my opinion. I am by no means the definitive authority.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that 'output' type extensions are not available as verbs in the verb list, in contrary to 'effect' type extensions. I couldn't find any of the others, either.

There's a shell script for DXF 12 included with Inkscape (/usr/share/extensions/ps2dxf.sh). It can convert postscript files programmatically to dxf - using pstoedit. Maybe that's an option for you.

Comment: I am interested in DXF or gcode. Can you confirm the `ps2pdf.sh` option? And would I have to save the SVG as PS by some other means?

Comment: Yes, it would require to export to ps (Inkscape can do that programmatically). Not sure what you mean by 'confirm the option'?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to convert SVG to DXF and your answer seemed to be for PS to PDF, so I wanted to confirm that PS to PDF would also work for SVG to DXF.

Comment: I didn't try, but it should work to programmatically export from SVG to PS, and then use the script (or the commands it contains) to do the next conversion to dxf.

Comment: I could not find such script `ps2pdf.sh`, as this bash command returned no results: `find / -name ps2pdf.sh 2>/dev/null`. I do have `ps2pdf` installed and the `man` page shows it's only for PDF: `ps2pdf - Convert PostScript to PDF using ghostscript`. So I won't pursue this solution.

Comment: That script is in /usr/share/inkscape/extensions. It's called ps2dxf.sh, I'm very sorry about the typo.

Comment: Due to the pandemic, I didn't get a chance to test this, and now I've moved on and am unlikely to do so. But thank you for your help!